# How to join the output of 2 nested loops next to each other?

Tags: java, for-loop, nested, ascii-art

So I'm currently working on a personal project and I made a program that prints out star patterns. On one of the star patterns I want this output:

**Figure**

```
*        *
**      **
***    ***
****  ****
**********
```

So I made one method print out this:

**Figure 1**

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print("*" + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

And another method print out this:

**Figure 2**

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 2 * (n - i); j >= 0; j--) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print("* ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

**My question:** How can I put the first method stars next to the other method stars?

This is what I got so far:

```java
public static void printStarsVictory(int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print("*" + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 2 * (n - i); j >= 0; j--) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

This is what is printing so far:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on the right track you just need to combine your two programs into the inner for loop:

```
private static void printStarsVictory(int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < n * 2; j++) {
            if (j <= i || j >= (n * 2 - i)) {
                System.out.print("*");
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Example Usage `printStarsVictory(5)`:**

```
*       *
**     **
***   ***
**** ****
*********
```

**Example Usage `printStarsVictory(12)`:**

```
*                     *
**                   **
***                 ***
****               ****
*****             *****
******           ******
*******         *******
********       ********
*********     *********
**********   **********
*********** ***********
***********************
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, System.out.println() prints only to the next row, not to the right. The only way is to create a new algorithm. You should put everything into single loop.

```
// loop starts from 0 and user counts from 1, so we wil decrement it by 1
n--;

// this loops moves pointer vertically
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    // this loops moves pointer horisontally
    for (int j = 0; j < n*2; j++) {

        // here we choose what to print
        if (j <= i || j >= n*2-i) {
            System.out.print("*");
        } else System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Your answer is lacking clarity. Can you please edit it and make it clear? Ex. Add Example, Show Code etc

Comment: now it should work better, I have also added some comments

Comment: Just looked at this for the first time... This does not produce the expected output for either an even or positive `n`.

Answer (score 1):

Each row has the increasing number of stars and decreasing number of spaces.

e.g. For `n=5` first row has 2 stars at each side and 8 spaces.

At each iteration you can increase stars and decrease spaces and print them on the same line:

```
public static void printStarsVictory(int n) {

    int sp = n * 2 - 2; // number of spaces

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        printStars(i); // print stars on the left side
        int temp = sp;
        while (temp > 0) {
            System.out.print(" ");
            temp--;
        }
        printStars(i); // // print stars on the right side
        System.out.println(""); 
        sp -= 2; // decrease spaces on each side 
    }
}

public static void printStars(int i) {
    while(i>0) {
        System.out.print("*");
        i--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you keep them in an array before printing to output:

```
public static void printStarsVictory(int n) {
    StringBuilder[] lines = new StringBuilder[n + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        lines[i] = new StringBuilder();
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            lines[i].append("*" + " ");
        }

        for (int j = 2 * (n - i - 1); j > 0; j--) {
            lines[i].append(" ");
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 2 * (n - i - 1); j > 0; j--) {
            lines[i].append(" ");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            lines[i].append("* ");
        }
    }

    for (StringBuilder line : lines) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can visualize this *figure* as a matrix of numbers in a range: `[-n, 0]` inclusive vertically and `[-n, n]` inclusive horizontally, where each point is:

```java
m[i][j] = Math.abs(i) - Math.abs(j);
```

If `n = 4`, then this matrix looks like this:

```
  0  1  2  3  4  3  2  1  0
 -1  0  1  2  3  2  1  0 -1
 -2 -1  0  1  2  1  0 -1 -2
 -3 -2 -1  0  1  0 -1 -2 -3
 -4 -3 -2 -1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVBNT8MwDL33V1g9pYhGHDhlYhwQBw4Th3FDHNw2dMnypcSdhNB@e8nKVpCYJp4s2Xp@z5atcYe1D9LpbjuOygYfCXQm@UDK8ERRouVPjtZTtSiKMDRGtdAaTAlWqBx8FpBx5BMh5bTzqgObuywbletf3wBjn6qj@ADlCBzcwe1ipuY9PKLr5YPxSXasdtdwU82iE7jFwFZIGyGwSWf6QcotU1AvL8x1f33/nf9b9@KfG830YZeCJWi4hxJyCCivoLzgfffxEdsNW38kkpb7gYQI@WFUnTnoJJ5u@nHwyWAcq6rvV@6L/Th@AQ)

```java
int n = 4;
IntStream.rangeClosed(-n, 0)
        .map(Math::abs)
        .peek(i -> IntStream.rangeClosed(-n, n)
                .map(Math::abs)
                .mapToObj(j -> i > j ? "  " : "* ")
                .forEach(System.out::print))
        .forEach(i -> System.out.println());
```

Output:

```
*               * 
* *           * * 
* * *       * * * 
* * * *   * * * * 
* * * * * * * * *
```

---

<sup>See also: [Making an hourglass using asterisks in java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66790387/15402945)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66791149/16275053), you can use two nested *for loops* and one *if else statement* in the same way:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 9;
    for (int i = -n; i <= 0; i++) {
        for (int j = -n; j <= n; j++)
            if (Math.abs(i) <= Math.abs(j)
                    // in chessboard order
                    && (i + j) % 2 == 0
                    // vertical borders
                    || Math.abs(j) == n)
                System.out.print("*");
            else
                System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
*                 *
**               **
* *             * *
** *           * **
* * *         * * *
** * *       * * **
* * * *     * * * *
** * * *   * * * **
* * * * * * * * * *
** * * * * * * * **
```

---

<sup>See also:

• [How to print a given diamond pattern in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68093276/16275053)

• [Empty diamond shape with numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68093382/16275053)</sup>